# php add html tags according to the div width

Tags: php

How to add html tags according to the div width?

Php code to output html:

```
echo '<div>'; 
$json = json_decode($json_data);
foreach ($json as $data){
    echo '<p>'.$data->title.'</p>';
}
echo '</div>';
```

this will out put:

```
<div>
<p>TWELFTH NIGHT</p>
<p>MERRY CHRISTMAS</p>
<p>CHRISTMAS GIFT</p>
<p>XMAS</p>
<p>HARD CANDY CHRISTMAS</p>
<p>GOD REST YE MERRY, GENTLEMEN</p>
<p>GOD SPEED THE PLOUGH; PLOUGH MONDAY</p>
<p>CHRISTMAS CARDS </p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
div{padding:0;margin:0;width:500px;overflow:hidden;float:left;}
p{float:left;font-size:12px;font-family:arial sans-serif;padding:0 10px 0 10px}
h2{padding:0 10px 0 10px;}
```

SEE REVIEW IN http://jsfiddle.net/sRVsP/

some `p` will turn line, because the `div` width is only `500px`. And I want to add `<h2>toggle</h2>` at the end of first line (`<h2>toggle</h2>` including in `500px`)

SEE after insert `<h2>toggle</h2>` in http://jsfiddle.net/sRVsP/1/

It could easy to do with jquery, but difficult in php. may be I should count each words width like this:

```
$json = json_decode($json_data);
foreach ($json as $data){
    echo (strlen($data->title)*7+20).'<br />';
}
```

`6px-7px` for font width of `font-size:12px;font-family:arial sans-serif;`, `20px` for left right padding, then do something judge width `words width plus`, it also should consider the insert `<h2>toggle</h2>` width...

So can anyone give me some good way to solve my question? Automatic insert `<h2>toggle</h2>` at the end of first line, if too many `p` will turn line in a div?

may be my thought is not a right... Thanks.

Comment: PHP has no concept of what a page is going to look like in somebody's browser.  It also can't parse CSS like it can HTML so it can't get information like how wide you've set a div to be from it.  I think your only option might be to rethink your page design.

Comment: @GordonM, yes i also know php cannot parse css, so do you have some advise for re-design my situation? thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is obviously way overkill to do in php. I suggest using a jQuery plugin like [this one](http://shakenandstirredweb.com/240/jquery-moreless-text) to limit the height of the div and put a "show more" button underneath the `div`.